# WCF (WCF-Binding) in/with C/C++

Tags: c#, c++, c, wcf, wcf-binding

Is thare any like WCF libs (OpenSourse) written in  C\C++?
Or at least some kined of special WCF C++ services (NOT ON Basic HTTP Binding)?

Comment: please give more info what you want exactly

Comment: 1) WCF libs (Open Source) written in C\C++ 2) Any WCF C++ services examples (NOT WITH Basic HTTP Binding)

Comment: Ole: Please explain more about what it is that you want. Your comment just repeats what you wrote in your original question.

Comment: some lib or project which should be Open Source written in C\C++ for creating WCF services with C\C++ that can integrate or talk to with WCF services written in C# NOT using Basic HTTP Binding. So in case such libs or projects do not exist, any example\way of how such thing (WCF C++ service example (NOT WITH Basic HTTP Binding)) can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is a C++-based library for exposing and consuming web-services supporting the WS-* protocols (i.e. like WS-Security). In that case, you could probably give [Axis2/C](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/index.html) a try. It's the C version of the normal Java-based Axis2 from Apache.

(There's also [Axis/CPP](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html), but not sure how up-to-date that is).